# How to add a host to the known_host file with ansible?

Tags: ansible

I want to add the ssh key for my private git server to the known_hosts file with ansible 1.9.3 but it doesn't work.

I have the following entry in my playbook:

```
- name: add SSH host key
  known_hosts: name='myhost.com'
               key="{{ lookup('file', 'host_key.pub') }}"
```

I have copied /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub to host_key.pub and the file looks like:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1... root@myhost.com
```

If I run my playbook I always get the following error message:

```
TASK: [add SSH host key]
****************************************************** 
failed: [default] => {"cmd": "/usr/bin/ssh-keygen -F myhost.com -f /tmp/tmpe5KNIW", "failed": true, "rc": 1}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you manually run the command `ssh-keygen -v -F myhost.com -f /path/to/host_key.pub`.  That's effectively the same command that Ansible is attempting to invoke, so it will hopefully report the error that Ansible is encountering.  Make sure you run the command as the same user that the playbook is running as.

Answer (score 11):

You can directly use `ssh-keyscan` within the ansible task:

```
- name: Ensure servers are present in known_hosts file
  known_hosts:
    name: "{{ hostvars[item].ansible_host }}"
    state: present
    key: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'ssh-keyscan {{ hostvars[item].ansible_host }}') }}"
    hash_host: true
  with_items: "{{ groups.servers }}"
```

In the above snipped, we iterate over all hosts in the group "servers" defined in your inventory, use `ssh-keyscan` on them, read the result with `pipe` and add it using `known_hosts`.

If you have only one host that you want to add, it's even simpler:

```
- name: Ensure server is present in known_hosts file
  known_hosts:
    name: "myhost.com"
    state: present
    key: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'ssh-keyscan myhost.com') }}"
    hash_host: true
```

Whether you need `hash_host` or not depends on your system.

Comment: I used this solution with one change that I added ip addresses directly to the with_items section. However, there's a bit of a strange randomly appearing problem with the error "No key specified when adding a host" for some ip addresses. I can't quite figure out why that is. One ip always fails while others fail randomly.

Comment: The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object' has no attribute 'ansible_host'. Could never get past this error.

Answer (score 8):

Your copy of the remote host public key needs a name, that name needs to match what you specify for your known hosts.

In your case, prepend `"myhost.com "` to your **host_key.pub** key file as follows:

```
myhost.com ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1... root@myhost.com
```

Reference:
**Ansible** [known_hosts module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/known_hosts_module.html), specifically the **name** parameter

Answer (score 3):

Use ssh-keyscan to generate host_key.pub is another way.

```
ssh-keyscan myhost.com > host_key.pub
```

This command will generate the format like this.

```
$ ssh-keyscan github.com > github.com.pub
# github.com SSH-2.0-libssh-0.7.0
# github.com SSH-2.0-libssh-0.7.0

$ cat github.com.pub 
github.com ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAq2A7hRGmdnm9tUDbO9IDSwBK6TbQa+PXYPCPy6rbTrTtw7PHkccKrpp0yVhp5HdEIcKr6pLlVDBfOLX9QUsyCOV0wzfjIJNlGEYsdlLJizHhbn2mUjvSAHQqZETYP81eFzLQNnPHt4EVVUh7VfDESU84KezmD5QlWpXLmvU31/yMf+Se8xhHTvKSCZIFImWwoG6mbUoWf9nzpIoaSjB+weqqUUmpaaasXVal72J+UX2B+2RPW3RcT0eOzQgqlJL3RKrTJvdsjE3JEAvGq3lGHSZXy28G3skua2SmVi/w4yCE6gbODqnTWlg7+wC604ydGXA8VJiS5ap43JXiUFFAaQ==
```

Comment: `ssh-keyscan -t ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 myhost.com > test1.pub` is better for known_hosts

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
---
- name: Add SSH keys of all hosts to known_hosts
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Scan for SSH host keys
      ansible.builtin.command: ssh-keyscan -H -p {{ hostvars[item].ansible_port | default(22) }} {{ item }} 
      register: ssh_scan
      loop: "{{ groups['all'] }}"
      changed_when: false

    - name: Ensure .ssh directory exists
      ansible.builtin.file:
        path: "/home/user/.ssh"
        state: directory
        mode: '0700'

    - name: Add SSH host keys to known_hosts
      ansible.builtin.known_hosts:
        path: "/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts"
        name: "{% if hostvars[item.item].ansible_port is defined and hostvars[item.item].ansible_port != 22 %}[{{ item.item }}]:{{ hostvars[item.item].ansible_port }}{% else %}{{ item.item }}{% endif %}"
        key: "{{ item.stdout }}"
        state: present
      loop: "{{ ssh_scan.results }}"
      when: item.rc == 0
```

Just make sure to customise /home/user/.ssh/known_host